# Linked contacts

Tags: contacts

If one of my contacts changes their number, and I am unaware, and somebody else got that number as their new number, would it link the new person to that number in my contacts automatically

Comment: What app are you talking about? The telephone or contacts app or a third party messenger like WhatsApp? Telephony and contacts app will not do anything. A phone number in a contact is a phone number. Unless you change the number or add a new contact, even a phone number that has changed years ago will stay the same in your contact list. Nothing will be added, nothing deleted unless you do it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. The phone number is the unique key.  There is no way for the phone to know otherwise.

It is different in an app like WhatsApp. Even though the link is by phone number, the number can be changed by the owner of that account.

Comment: Supporting documentary references of any kind that you could provide?